# Windows Blue screen of death Inaccesible boot device After BIOS Factory Default

Tags: bios, bsod, factory-defaults

I had a friend do something in BIOS, which resulted in a "Non-system Disk failure," so he reverted to Factory BIOS, and now I get an Inaccessible boot device BSOD. I'm using some Kingston SSD.

Perhaps wrong disk config e.g. RAID, SATA stuff?

My first post here btw. (I've done stack overflow, but any feedback helps!)
How should I change my BIOS to use my computer again?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1) Which OS is installed on the drive? 2) Do you know the make and model of the motherboard? 3) What was the friend intending to do before it went wrong?

Comment: Yeah, inaccessible boot device is typically triggered by SATA controller mode change (since it relies on different driver in AHCI and RST/RAID mode respectively). With recent Intel platform the trigger could be something called VMD instead (which is pretty much a redesigned / reworked RST). So toggling the setting could likely get him out of the problem (well, at least the IBD one; not sure about the original problem you mentioned).

Comment: @AndrewMorton 1.Windows 10, 2. nope I can check,3. Remove Intel DHCP network Boot or something.

Comment: It was AHCI ig.

Answer (score -1):

If anybody else had the problem, it was my SATA, so you should look up the correct SATA config. (Mine was AHCI)